# How do I install the DV4mini software on Ubuntu?

Tags: digital-modes, software, linux, d-star

The [documentation](http://wirelesshold.com/manuals.aspx) says the following:

> The program requires the complete installation of Mono. You install for example with apt-get the packet mono-complete.
>
> Until an installation packet is available at a later time the installation has to be done manually. Download the proper zip file to your PC. (http://dv4m.ham-dmr.ch) and unpack it into a directory of your choice below the home directory.
>
> In order to gain access to the USB/serial interface the user account must become a member of the group “dialout”. Open the Console and enter `sudo gpasswd —add myusername dialout`
>
> The DV4mini program gets started by entering `mono dv4mini.exe` in the console or you can create a desktop icon.

The link from the manual seems dead; it redirects to [a German website](http://www.dv4mini.de/edownload.html) for the DV4 mini; it has no `.zip`s containing the necessary files (`dv4mini.exe`, `dmr`, `dstar`, and `dv_serial`) to download, only `setup.exe` installer-files that Mono won't run:

```
elliottcable@ham-vm ~/Downloads $ mono ./2017_12_10_setup.exe 
Cannot open assembly './2017_12_10_setup.exe': File does not contain a valid CIL image.
```

Frankly, I'm a little stuck. I'm a pretty-experienced developer and *nix user, but I've never used any Windows / Mono stuff before.

How the hell do I get my DV4mini software running on “PC-Linux?”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first link on the German website leads to a .zip file: [link](http://www.dv4mini.de/EU_2017_06_03_2_setup.zip).

That zip file only contains the installer.

You'll have to run the installer using `wine` (Wine is easy to install under Ubuntu), and then you can run the program itself from the installation directory using `mono`.

Comment: Ah, I edited the original question. I knew there was a `.zip` file, but I meant, "no files as-described by the manual — only installer files." But that worked! I forgot `wine` existed, and was separate thing from `mono`. Windows! `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`